# In InstallShield, how to change the value of my Property before it is used by SQL Text Replacement?

Tags: sql, windows-installer, installshield, installscript

**What I want to do**

In InstallShield I want to set the value of a Property before it is used by the SQL Text Replacement feature. I want the new Property value to come from an Edit control that I've added to a dialog.

**What I've done so far**

I have added SQL Scripts to my InstallShield project, which include placeholders for InstallShield's Text Replacement feature. I've used the Text Replacement tab to find and replace a placeholder in the SQL script with the value of a Property that I've added to the Property Manager. This works correctly, but only for the Property's default value.

**Where I'm stuck**

The problem is that I want the new value to come from an Edit control in my custom Dialog, but I can't find a way to do this. Text Replacement always uses the Property's default value.

What I've tried is the following InstallScript, which runs when the user clicks Next on my custom Dialog:

```
CtrlGetText("MyDialog", EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER, svValueFromUser);
MsiSetProperty ( hwndDlg, "EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER", svValueFromUser);
```

Where EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER is my Property. This runs without error, but the value doesn't come through to the final SQL script.

Why isn't the new value for EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER being used by SQL Text Replacement? How can I diagnose why it's not working? Should I be doing this in a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be because I wasn't using the system property ISMSI_HANDLE.

So the correct code to write a Property from an Edit control in a custom dialog is:

```
CtrlGetText("MyDialog", EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER, svValueFromUser);
MsiSetProperty (ISMSI_HANDLE, "EDIT_VALUE_FROM_USER", svValueFromUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your property isn't listed in the SecureCustomPublicProperties property and is getting set back to it's default value when the installer transitions to the install execute sequence.  A log file of the installation would give more data to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've actually found the problem was a simple mistake in my code.